# .sdf file is giving error to open

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce-4

This is my first ASP.NET MVC3 application and it is working and everything is fine except to open DB file (`.sdf`) in `App_Data` folder. I am getting error

> the operation could not be completed. Unspecified error.

Things which is done from my side are:

1. All the operations like Show all files, Include in project etc.. are done on this folder and files.
2. SQL Server Compact 4.0 (runtime + tools support) is installed to my machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with MVC 4. Installing VS2010 SP1 fixed it for me.

[VS2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)